# what's the concept of mandatory in orientdb?

Tags: database, concept, orientdb

I'm trying OrientDB.

Most of concepts are easy and clear to understand. But there was one unfamiliar concept. The `mandatory`. What's this?

Answer (score 6):

Are you talking about mandatory schema properties? If yes this means you can use OrientDB in schema-less mode but defining some properties as mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory means you have to provide a value for that property when creating a new instance/row. It's like SQL's "Not Null"

Comment: OrientDB also has a "Not Null" property, so I'm thinking it's probably more like Lvca's definition

Answer (score 1):

"Mandatory"on a field of a document indicate that you are using your Document in Schema-Hybrid (Schema-Mixed) mode, as you can see from documentation (by the way it's seems all new, great!)
when you set your schema in schema-full mode "enable the strict-mode at class level and set all the fields as mandatory", so if you are in schema-mixed mode and you want to insert a new document you have to indicate all the fields that are marked with "mandatory" even if their are null